# ManytoMany operation

Tags: hibernate

please i need help 
i have 2 class (`Bulettin`,`Matier`) with association(`Bulletin_Matier`) `ManytoMany` 
i need to list all Matier that have `idBulletin=X` with hibernate criteria or namedquery

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Bulletin")

public class Bulletin implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
        private Integer id;
        @Column(name = "etat", nullable = true)
        private String etat;
        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name="Bulletin_Matier", 
                  joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Bull_ID"),
                  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Matier_ID"))
        private List<Matier> Matiers;

 ----------------------------------
```

AND

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MATIER")
public class Matier implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "LIBELLE", nullable = true)
    private String libelle;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "Matiers")
    private List<Bulletin> Bulletins;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `Criteria` or Named Queries for this. Try this,

```
 public List<Matier> getMatierList(Integer idBulletin){
     Bulletin bulletin = (Bulletin) session.get(Bulletin.class, idBulletin);
     return bulletin.getMatiers();
 }
```